# Option to Comment not showing on News Feed

Tags: newsfeed, comments, sharepoint-news

While we used to have the option to comment on posts, that has since disappeared and we only have the options in the screen shot. I do not remember changing any settings. We also have the "Feedback" button that I which I thought was supposed to be removed by now (not as critical).[image: news feed options bar]

[image: news feed options bar zoomed in]

Answer (score 0):

Found the setting in Classic Admin center. I don't remember changing this but maybe I did.
[image: Classic Admin Center settings]